# Sending file to secured SOAP web service using apache http client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-httpclient-4.x

There is a SOAP service written which is for any file transfer. I need to call that service using `apache http client`library.

First thing to be noted is that the service is secured with password digest. I have username and password.

Second, I need to pass a file as an attachment.

I have come across the following code

```
void post(String strURL, String strSoapAction,  String strXMLFilename) throws Exception{

        File input = new File(strXMLFilename);
        PostMethod post = new PostMethod(strURL);
        RequestEntity entity = new FileRequestEntity(input, "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");
        post.setRequestEntity(entity);
        post.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", strSoapAction);
        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
        try {
            int result = httpclient.executeMethod(post);
            System.out.println("Response status code: " + result);
            System.out.println("Response body: ");
            System.out.println(post.getResponseBodyAsString());
        } finally {
            post.releaseConnection();
        }
    }
```

But, i think the above piece of code doesn't include **security considerations** and also the **file attachment** piece of code.
Can someone please let me know the changes to be done in order to include these two things(security and file attachment) in the above code.