# Sending file to secured SOAP web service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I need to write a client that calls a SOAP web service. I am given `wsdl` and a `SOAP request`. It is a secured web service and a file as an attachment is passed to the service.I have tested it using `SOAP UI` but need to write a Java program to call the service.

Here is the wsdl

```
<definitions xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/integration/b2b" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" name="WS_VT_SECURED_INBOUND" targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/integration/b2b">
<types>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/integration/b2b">
<element name="TransportFileRequest">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element minOccurs="1" name="FileName" type="string"/>
<element minOccurs="1" name="FileType" type="string"/>
<element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="messageID" type="string"/>
<element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="senderID" type="string"/>
<element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="checksum" type="string"/>
<element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="timestamp" type="string"/>
<element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="transportVersion" type="string"/>
<element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="payload" type="anyType"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="TransportFileResponse">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Status" type="string"/>
<element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="ErrorMessage" type="string"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="error" type="string"/>
</schema>
</types>
<message name="TransportFileResponseMessage">
<part name="FileTransportResponse" element="tns:TransportFileResponse"></part>
</message>
<message name="faultMessage">
<part name="faultMessage" element="tns:error"></part>
</message>
<message name="TransportFileRequestMessage">
<part name="FileTransportRequest" element="tns:TransportFileRequest"></part>
</message>
<portType name="TransportFilePort">
<operation name="sendFile">
<input message="tns:TransportFileRequestMessage"></input>
<output message="tns:TransportFileResponseMessage"></output>
<fault name="faultMessage" message="tns:faultMessage"></fault>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="TransportFilePortBinding" type="tns:TransportFilePort">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="sendFile">
<soap:operation soapAction="sendFile" style="document"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
<fault name="faultMessage">
<soap:fault name="faultMessage" use="literal"/>
</fault>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="receiveFile_WS_VT_SECURED_INBOUND">
<port name="TransportFilePort_pt" binding="tns:TransportFilePortBinding">
<soap:address location="https://hostname:9443/wsx/services/receiveFile_WS_VT_SECURED_INBOUND"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

And this is the SOAP request looks like

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:b2b="http://xmlns.oracle.com/integration/b2b">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <b2b:TransportFileRequest>
          <b2b:FileName>120_VERMONT_ACH_Sanity11march1.dat</b2b:FileName>
         <b2b:FileType>120</b2b:FileType>
         <b2b:MessageID>3454</b2b:MessageID>
         <b2b:SenderID>ekrjekrj</b2b:SenderID>
         <b2b:checksum>b2ee8af554ab6933085d341b71765bc8</b2b:checksum>
         <b2b:timestamp>3434</b2b:timestamp>
         <b2b:transportServiceVersion>4343</b2b:transportServiceVersion>
         <b2b:payload>120_VERMONT_ACH_Sanity11march1.dat</b2b:payload>
      </b2b:TransportFileRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In the above, file attachment is

```
<b2b:payload>120_VERMONT_ACH_Sanity11march1.dat</b2b:payload>
```

I know there can be multiple ways to do that like using `apache http client` library or any other. But i have never worked with Web service so doesn't know much about it. Even though I had started with apache http client but couldn't do it. For apache issue I had posted one question [Sending file to secured SOAP web service using apache http client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658949/sending-file-to-secured-soap-web-service-using-apache-http-client) but there is no solution provided so far.
There is no compulsion that same has to be achieved using apache http client.

Please let me know how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a JAX-WS compliant framework like [Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) or [CXF](https://cxf.apache.org/) and follow the top-down approach.

These frameworks provide tools which will help you generate the proper Java client classes starting from the WSDL.

If you want to use HTTP Client, you will have to handle the SOAP envelopes yourself, using the classes in `java.xml.soap`. See [`SOAPMessage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage.html)